# Python Pandas Calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the cost of cars that sit at a meter. I almost have the results I want, but it seems as if my `if` statement is being ignored and only executing my `else` statement.

Here is my input:

```
vehicle = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')
    Zone; rate; Minutes; max time(hr)
     5  ; 4.5 ;  2880  ;   2 
     5  ; 3.5 ;  902   ;   2 
     5  ; 2.0 ;  1440  ;   2 
     6  ; 2.0 ;  1440  ;   3 
     6  ; 3.5 ;  1439  ;   3 
     6  ; 2.5 ;  630   ;   3 
     6  ; 2.0 ;  751   ;   3
```

Code

```
max_time_mins = vehicle['max time']* 1440
max_rate = 20

x = vehicle['Minutes'] >= max_time_mins
x = str(x)

if x == True:
    cost = ((((vehicle['Minutes']%1440)/60)*vehicle['rate'])+ (vehicle['Minutes']/1440) * max_rate)


else:
    cost = ((vehicle['Minutes']/60)*vehicle['rate'])
```

I convert `max_time_mins` to minutes and then compare to see if the vehicle parked duration `Minutes` is greater or equal to the max time a vehicle can park which you see in [x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr38C.jpg), because if `Minutes` >= `max_time_mins` I would like to add an additional charge, `max_rate`

The resulting im getting is:

```
0    216.000000
1     52.616667
2     48.000000
3     48.000000
4     83.941667
5     26.250000
6     25.033333
```

All the results are correct except the first instance resulting in 216.

I'm sure there's a more efficient way of writing this, but right now this is what I have, so please any advice or suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Hi, please provide the input in the question itself so people can copy it and try your code on it.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. The links to the images are annoying. I'll gladly reverse it once you change it.

Comment: it's more useful to post data as text, not images; it's even more useful to post it as a command so I can copy/paste it into my python console

Comment: why are you converting x to a string?

Comment: Do you want this condition considered for each row individually? There's a very different way to approach this code if that's what you want out.

Comment: Hi. apologies ill make changes to the question.

Comment: @MohammadAthar I converted x as a str because I was receiving this error: 
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Hi @scnerd yes I would like the condition to consider each row, I just figure that pandas automatically did this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do a for loop to perform this kind of operation in pandas. This can be done using a mask (see [this page of documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for more info on boolean indexing in pandas). For insatnce:

```
max_rate = 20
max_time_mins = vehicle['max time'] * 1440
```

This multiplies by 1440 element-wise. That is, each row is multiplied by the constant.

```
x = vehicle['Minutes'] >= max_time_mins 
# Output
# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2    False
# 3    False
# 4    False
# 5    False
# 6    False
# dtype: bool
```

This comparison is also performed element-wise. Therefore, the output is a boolean Series with the same length which will contain `True` if the element of that row fulfills the condition and `False` otherwise.

That is why you got the error `Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` when you tried to do `if x == True:`, because the if statement does not work element-wise.

However, with boolean indexing this if...else... behaviour can be easily replicated using the mask already defined and the element-wise not operator `~`:

```
cost = pd.Series(np.empty(vehicle.shape[0])) # initialize a Series with the same shape
cost.loc[x] = ((((vehicle['Minutes'][x]%1440)/60)*vehicle['rate'][x])+ (vehicle['Minutes'][x]/1440) * max_rate) # Equivalent to if
cost.loc[~x] = ((vehicle['Minutes'][~x]/60)*vehicle['rate'][~x]) # Equivalent to else
# Output
# 0    40.000000
# 1    52.616667
# 2    48.000000
# 3    48.000000
# 4    83.941667
# 5    26.250000
# 6    25.033333
# dtype: float64
```

Which could also be added directly to the original dataframe as a new column:

```
vehicle.loc[x, 'cost'] = ((((vehicle['Minutes'][x]%1440)/60)*vehicle['rate'][x])+ (vehicle['Minutes'][x]/1440) * max_rate)
# Here vehicle has values in rows where x is true and NaN everywhere else 
vehicle.loc[~x, 'cost'] = ((vehicle['Minutes'][~x]/60)*vehicle['rate'][~x])
# The rest of the rows are filled
```

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer! I just did not know how to index in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition in if statement.

It is set to if `x == True.Ambiguous`.

If `x` has any value, statement will be true.

So, to make long story short, try redefining that condition.

You could also try defining cost variable outside that condition and then comparing `x` to it, not `x` to `True`.